# Can't use data-toggle attribute with h:commandLink

Tags: jsf, twitter-bootstrap, facelets, commandlink

I want to convert the following  tag into JSFs h:commandLink, but I'm having trouble with the data-toggle attribute.

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

This is what I converted it into:

```
<h:commandLink styleClass="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

As far as I'm concearned, the commandLink is rendered as a HTML -tag. But the dropdown menu is unusable, after rewriting into JSF. Any ideas?

Greetings, Beejay

Comment: Exact what html code <h:commandLink styleClass="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> render?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom HTML tag attributes are not rendered by JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf)

Comment: @JohanNordli: It schould render to `<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle=dropdown">`
@BalusC: Thanks, I'll have a look at that

Comment: @BalusC: Thx for your link, sadly it couldn't help me. Method 3 would have been the best solution but neither importing the passthrough namespace nor the passThroughtAttribute worked for me. Any other ideas? I am not allowed to use any cutomized renderers, since I'm more or less working on a company project