# JSF commandButton add custom attributes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, commandbutton

I need add custom attributes to a commandButton this attributes are required to work a bootstrap modal, I using h:commandButton

```
data-toggle="modal" 
data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" 

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions to bypass the fact that JSF components do not render custom HTML attributes.

See here : [Custom HTML tag attributes are not rendered by JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf)