# handling mouse events inside jsf tags

Tags: jsf

I have the following snippet from the jsp. I want to limit the data set to 'n' characters when the user tries to copy and paste using the keyboard and when user copies and paste using the mouse. onKeyUp works perfectly without any issue.But i am not able to find anything for mouse events. Things like onPaste wont work in jsf, i suppose

```html
<t:column style="width:16%,valign:top;" >
<t:htmlTag value="strong">
<t:outputText value="field detailed description"></t:outputText></t:htmlTag></t:column>      
    <t:column style="width:66%,valign:top;" >
   <t:column style="width:66%,valign:top;" >
   <t:inputTextarea  id="description" styleClass="control-xxlarge" rows="5" cols="40" value="#     {manageBean.someNotes}"        
        onkeyup="charCount(this,500);" >
</t:inputTextarea>            
</t:column> 

<script>
function charCount(field,maxlimit){
   if(field.value.length>=maxlimit)
       field.value=field.value.substring(0,maxlimit-1); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom HTML tag attributes are not rendered by JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf)

Answer (score 0):

The JSF element `inputTextArea` supports JS events such as `onchange` or `onclick`.

See documentation : http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_inputTextarea.html

You could add : `onchange="charCount(this,500);"`

Comment: OP's asking about custom attribues like `onPage`