# What different between p:param and custom attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I suspect about 2 way of passing value through attribute.

First: f:param

```
<p:inputText value="#{inputTextView.inputVal}">
    <f:param name="fieldA" value="inputA" />
    <p:ajax process="@form" update="@form"></p:ajax>
</p:inputText>
```

Second: custom field

```
<p:inputText value="#{inputTextView.inputVal}"
             fieldB="inputB">
    <p:ajax process="@form" update="@form"></p:ajax>
</p:inputText>
```

The first way, I can get value of attribute by using

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("fieldA");
```

While the second way use

```
UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getAttributes().get("fieldB");
```

Does anyone know what different between first and second?

What situation which appropriate for use the first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to set a custom attribute, you cannot just add a random new attribute to a tag because JSF ignores unsupported tag attributes. BalusC gives some options on how to work around this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16668769/2593804).

`f:param` should be used if you want to add values to the query string or request parameters. It should be used with command components (e.g. `h:commandButton`, `h:commandLink` or `h:outputLink`).

`f:attribute` on the other hand, adds entries to the attribute Map of a component.