# JQuery-mobile + JSF navigation dosn't work together

Tags: jsf, jquery-mobile, navigation

I ran into a problem. I am using a command button in JSF like this

```
<h:form> 
    <h:commandButton value="Next" action="#{handler.nextPage}" data-theme="a" />
</h:form>
```

In the backend I've a method returning "page2?faces-redirect=true"

Now, when i remove the

```
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

In my header it redirects me fine to the next page and show me the new URL of the second page. But when i have the jquery mobile-tag there...it goes to the next page and shows me the same URL as from the page I am comming from

Someone an idea how to fix that?

Comment: data-theme is not a jsf supported attribute, so it will get stripped of. Therfor you will not get the data-theme on the client side. For options on how to solve this, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf. Why removing the script tag makes it work is beyond my knowledge. Using any other frameworks?

Comment: I am using a HTML5 doctype so the theme is shown nicely, but somehow the jsf-navigation is messed up, when using jquery-mobile...