# Check whether a file has been chosen in p:fileUpload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces' simple `fileUpload` and a custom submit button, something like this:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p:fileUpload value="#{fileController.file}"
                  mode="simple"
                  skinSimple="true"
                  label="choose file"/>

    <p:commandButton value="upload"
                     ajax="false"
                     label="upload"
                     icon="fa fa-upload"
                     actionListener="#{fileController.upload}"/>
</h:form>
```

In the backing bean, `file` is a property of type `UploadedFile`.

Now I want to disable the `upload` button if no file is selected yet, but I fail to get the Information whether the user has selected a file or not the `file` property remains `null` until the `upload` button is clicked). I tried the `valueChangeListener` on the `<p:fileUpload>` component, but the event is only fired when I click the upload button (but then it's too late)

Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: Are you using JSF 2.2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You ultimately need a hook on the HTML DOM `change` event of `<input type="file">`. Without ajax (via `<p:ajax>`) that gets tricky with `<p:fileUpload mode="simple">` for 2 reasons:

- It doesn't support `onchange` attribute. It might be worth an [enhancement request](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues) to PF guys. Fortunately, since JSF 2.2 you can specify [passthrough attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf/).
- `skinSimple="true"` generates a `<span><span><input /></span></span>` and the passthrough attribute would render `onchange` on all those elements. You need an additional check if `this` is the `<input>` element.

All in all, here's how it could be done:

```
<html ... xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
...
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload label="choose file" mode="simple" skinSimple="true"
        value="#{bean.file}"
        a:onchange="if (tagName == 'INPUT') { if (!!value) PF('button').enable(); else PF('button').disable(); }" />

    <p:commandButton widgetVar="button" value="upload" 
        action="#{bean.upload}" ajax="false"
        disabled="#{facesContext.renderResponse or not facesContext.postback}" />
</h:form>
```

The condition in the `disabled` attribute of the button makes sure that it's only disabled during render response phase and an initial GET request. Otherwise JSF would refuse to queue the action event as per point 5 of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked/2120183#2120183).

The button is tied to the document as `widgetVar` so that JS could enable/disable it via its `enable()` and `disable()` functions.

Comment: unfortunately it's not working as expected, i get an error: 

Error Parsing XXX.xhtml: Error Traced[line: XXX] The prefix "a" for attribute "a:onchange" associated with an element type "p:fileUpload" is not bound.

Using primefaces 5.2 by the way and jsf 2.2.12

Comment: So you didn't click the "passthrough attributes" link to learn about it? I'll update the answer.

Comment: i clicked it, but didn't read it carefully enough it seems. Thanks again for this great answer, you seem to know everything about jsf.. respect

Comment: You're welcome. JSF is much easier if you know a bit of HTTP/HTML/CSS/JS (after all, that's what JSF is consuming and producing under the covers).