# p:datatable filter: cannot validate component with empty value

Tags: primefaces, apache-tomee, tomee-7

Is there a way to filter a p:datatable column by clicking on the text inside and making this text the filter ?

In other words, if I click on a session ID, I would like the datatable to filter this column by the clicked ID, as if I had entered it manually in the filter above ?

[image]

I am using Primefaces 6

**UPDATE**

This is my complete Datatable with the suggested solution:

```
<p:dataTable id="tablealltx" var="transaction" value="#{pastTxModel.txList}" paginator="true" rows="20" sortBy="#{transaction.createdDate}" sortOrder="descending" resizableColumns="true">             

    <p:column filterBy="#{transaction.session}" filterMatchMode="contains">

        <f:facet name="filter">
            <p:inputText id="myFilter" value="#{transactionXmlController.currentFilter}" onchange="PF('alltxform').filter()" />
        </f:facet>

        <p:outputLabel value="#{transaction.session}" ondblclick="document.getElementById('alltxform:tablealltx:myFilter').value = this.innerText;PF('tablealltx').filter()" >        
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

When I double click on the session, the value is entered in the filter text box, but the filtering itself does not work. Nothing happens.

I am using TomEE 7.0.1

**Solution**
Copy Paste from Jasper:

> The data table in your question doesn't have a widgetVar set to
>   tablealltx, so PF('tablealltx').filter() will fail. You can test it by
>   entering PF('tablealltx') in your browser's JavaScript console.

Comment: There is the event <p:ajax event="rowDblselect">. If you can get the clicked text in the filter-field I guess you can end with PF('datatablewv').filter(). I haven't tried it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by setting `widgetVar="myTable"` to the data table, using a custom filter field, replacing the cell contents with `p:outputLabel` (which has `ondblclick`) and JavaScript it all together:

```
<p:column headerText="Session" filterBy="#{transaction.session}" ...>
    <f:facet name="filter">
        <p:inputText id="myFilter"
                     value="#{myBean.myFilter}"
                     onchange="PF('myTable').filter()"/>
    </f:facet>
    <p:outputLabel value="#{transaction.session}"
                   ondblclick="document.getElementById('myForm:myTable:myFilter').value = this.innerText;PF('myTable').filter()"/>
</p:column>
```

For better readability, here's the `ondblclick`:

```
var filterId = 'myForm:myTable:myFilter';
document.getElementById(filterId).value = this.innerText;
PF('myTable').filter();
```

You could replace `p:outputLabel` with a simple `h:outputText`, but in that case (assuming you are on JSF 2.2+) you need to add the namespace `xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"`. Now you can use:

```
<h:outputText value="#{transaction.session}"
              a:ondblclick="..."/>
```

See also:

- [Custom HTML tag attributes are not rendered by JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf)

Comment: Almost there - this puts the text into the filter field but the filtering does not work: cannot validate component with empty value: alltxform:tablealltx:myFilter.

Comment: Did some googling. Seems this is due to an input without `value`. Probably that's JSF implementation related (I'm on Mojarra 2.2.7). I'll update the answer (it's working for me both with and without `value`).

Comment: Can't you use an `h:outputtext`? This is kind of wrong usage (abuse?)of an outputLabel

Comment: But the problem comes from the inputText. What is #{myBean.myFilter} bound to in your answer ?

Comment: Just a `String` property.

Comment: Filtering still does nothing. I see the ajax loader for a second, but nothing happens

Comment: The data table in your question doesn't have a `widgetVar` set to `tablealltx`, so `PF('tablealltx').filter()` will fail. You can test it by entering `PF('tablealltx')` in your browser's JavaScript console.

Comment: Make a small function of  the javascript for even better readability

Comment: @JasperdeVries the widgetVar  solved the problem. Thanks