# How to deal with "transient" input elements that have no backing bean representation?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, bean-validation, myfaces

I have come across some situations in which input controls are used that do not have the `value` attribute set, i.e. they have no direct representation in the backing bean.

User input is handled entirely by ajax listeners. An example are the input elements of the [column filters in the primefaces table](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml).

However, when dealing with such input fields, **MyFaces** warns me about each:

```
    Feb 09, 2017 3:04:51 PM javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator validate
    WARNING: cannot validate component with empty value: my_form:myTableId:j_id_1s
```

In a way, this problem has already been mentioned here: [p:datatable filter: cannot validate component with empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773150/pdatatable-filter-cannot-validate-component-with-empty-value)

My question is: What is the best practice in situations like this?

1. An input element should **always** have a reference in the backing bean, everything else is a design error
2. Just use a "dummy" value that points to an unused field in the bean.
3. Suppress the validation of that input element. (How?)
4. Suppress the MyFaces warning somehow. (How?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *1. An input element should **always** have a reference in the backing bean, everything else is a design error*

Not true.

---

> *2. Just use a "dummy" value that points to an unused field in the bean.*

No. That's ridiculous in short term and confusing in long term at best.

---

> *3. Suppress the validation of that input element. (How?)*

You could do. You can use [`<f:validateBean>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/validateBean.html) for that.

```
<h:inputXxx>
    <f:validateBean disabled="true" />
</h:inputXxx>
```

---

> *4. Suppress the MyFaces warning somehow. (How?)*

Based on [its source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-api/2.2.8/javax/faces/validator/BeanValidator.java/#132) there doesn't seem to be any way. You'd best [ask them](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES) to log it only during `Development` stage.