# How to set HTML5 data attribute in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

HTML5 introduced [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) that are often used by javascript library.

I need to **add one of those data attribute to a button generated with jsf**. For example, this jsf :

```
<h:commandButton value = "Click Me!" />
```

will generate the following html :

```
<input type="submit" value="Click Me!" />
```

How can I modify the jsf to have the following result :

```
<input type="submit" value="Click Me!" data-foo="bar" />
```

I tried by adding `<f:attribute name="data-foo" value="bar" />` but the html doesn't have it.

**How can i add a custom HTML attribute to a jsf generated HTML component ?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf

Comment: Good catch, thanks !