# How can I download react component in my JSF composite component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsf, babeljs

I made JSF component, which use react and react-select at its core. So in implementation JSF I download necessary js-library: react, react-select, babel and so far.

```
<script src="......react.development-16.3.1.js"/>
<script src="...../react-dom.development-16.13.0.js"></script>
<script src="....babel-6.26.0.min.js"></script> 
<script  src="....AutoCompleteSelect.js" type="text/babel" />
```

AutoCompleteSelect.js - here is my react component. So, i have to load it throug babel.js

It works correctly. But I need to render this component with new options regarding of selected value in  previously h:selectOneMenu element. And thats a problem. When I use <script ..> tag in my JSF composite component it work fine after loading page. But after rendering JSF component <script...> tags disappeared. And I get error in browser console. So I decided to use h:outputScript tag.  `<h:outputScript target="form" name="....react.development-16.3.1.js"/>` and so far. But outputScript doesn't have attribute type to indicate type="text/babel". How can I load my AutoCompleteSelect.js file throug babel.js in JSF component?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf) helps you. Just set the `type` parameter on the `h:outputScript`.

Comment: Thank you. It's definitelly worth to try.