# Apply the style of Primefaces to a vanilla jsf component?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I use Primefaces for my JSF app. In one page I have to use `<h:inputFile>` instead of the `<p:fileUpload>` equivalent. As a result, it renders without the Primeface style:

[image]

How can I apply the Primeface css style to `<h:inputFile>`? (to make it look like a Primefaces button for instance)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how the [basic `p:fileUpload`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml) is rendered. Copy the outputted HTML for the component and you are almost there.

You will notice that the actual `input type="file"` has an attribute `tabindex="-1"`, which you need add to your component. You should use a passthrough attribute to do so. See: [Custom HTML tag attributes are not rendered by JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf). So, add this namespace: `xmlns:a="http://java.sun.com/jsf/passthrough"`.

Another thing you need to take care of, is loading the stylesheets PrimeFaces is using to style the upload component. To do so, add:

```html
<h:outputStylesheet name="components.css" library="primefaces"/>
<h:outputStylesheet name="fileupload/fileupload.css" library="primefaces"/>
```

Note that you can leave out `components.css` if you are using other PrimeFaces components on your page.

In the end, your upload component will look like:

```html
<span class="ui-fileupload-simple ui-widget">
    <span class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left">
        <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-plusthick"></span>
        <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Choose</span>
        <h:inputFile a:tabindex="-1"/>
    </span>
</span>
```

Please note that you will be missing interactivity which is added to the PrimeFaces component by its JavaScript! My advice, just use `p:fileUpload`.